# How to draw straight line between two controls in a user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, line, draw

I have a usercontrol named groupControl: It has two flowlayoutpanel - source panel and destination panel. It also has a button.

I have another usercontrol named item. I will dynamically lay N item controls in source panel and M item controls in target panel.

I want there are straight lines between each item control and button on groupControl.

Finally I have a test form MainForm, it also contains a flowlayoutpanel. I will dynamically lay X groupcontrols on MainForm.

How could I draw straight lines between each usercontrol item and the button on the same groupControl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Visual Basic Power Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=371368A8-7FDC-441F-8E7D-FE78D96D4063) contains a DataRepeater, and some shapes (oval, rectangle..) including a line. See [this link](http://www.thevbprogrammer.com/VBNET_09/09-00-VBPowerPack.htm).

It is called "Visual Basic" Power Pack, but it can be used in a C# project without any hassle.

Look at the DataRepeater, not only it will help you to fill your panel with custom controls as items, but it contains what you need to put a line between them.

Comment: Thanks! I also use DevExpress 10.2 and .Net 4.0, is that ok?

Comment: It's ok. I think the Visual Basic Power Packs are already installed in Visual Studio 2010 : have a look to the "Visual Basic PowerPacks" tab in the ToolBox of the Windows forms designer.

Comment: Yes! It is there! Great! Thanks!

Comment: I have tried but I need this Lineshape generated and added to my panel dynamically at run time: I use LineShape line = new LineShape(...) and myPanel.Controls.Add(line);

Comment: It gives error Add can only take System.Windows.Forms.Control argument not this VB.PowerPacks type.

Comment: Oh, too bad, sorry I forgot about this. Try to use the DataRepeater instead. You can add your control inside as a template, and use databinding. By playing with BorderStyle property and setting ItemHeaderVisible to false, you can achieve having your controls separated by lines. Use a BindingList as datasources to get both your DataRepeaters updated automatically as you insert/remove elements.

Comment: great! I was trying to join controls with graphics.DrawLine(...) but because of the scrollbars every line drawn was dissappeared! 
The question is how to dynamically create LineShapes??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to edit something like this to fit your correct Start and End Points (`pt1` and `pt2`), but...

```
FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel2;

private void ShippingForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  using (Graphics g = e.Graphics) {
    Point pt1 = flowLayoutPanel1.Location;
    Point pt2 = flowLayoutPanel2.Location;
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black)) {
      g.DrawLine(p, pt1, pt2);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you have a form called `ShippingForm` (like I did above), go to the form's event handlers in the GUI and add double click on the `Pant` event to generate the empty method stub.
[image: VS's GUI of Form]

Comment: Where is the ShippingForm_Paint?

Comment: That'd just be the name of whatever your form is. I tested this on my application's form, which was called the ShippingForm. See edits above.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple. You can use the `ShapeContainer` class just as you would a `Canvas`. Set the parent of the `LineShape` to the `ShapeContainer` and the parent of the `ShapeContainer` to the `Form`.